# I'm running selenium in python, using the Firefox driver, but whenever I try to download and image from my desired website, nothing happens?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to click on a download button on a website, which seems to work well. however, even though the button is clicked, the download never happens. The code is a bit messy at the moment as I have tried searching for solutions, but without succes. I hope you guys are able to read it anyways.

this is the code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By as by
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities, FirefoxProfile 
import os

download_path = r"/root"
driver_options = FirefoxOptions()
driver_options.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
driver_options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/jpg, image/png, application/download, application/octet-stream");
driver_options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
driver_options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True);
driver_options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
driver_options.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
driver_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
driver_options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_path)
driver_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', options=driver_options)
driver.get('website.com')

username = driver.find_element(by.NAME, 'username')
password = driver.find_element(by.NAME, 'password')
username.send_keys('username')
password.send_keys('password')

login = driver.find_element(by.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]').click()

sleep(15)
try:
    hqelement = driver.find_element(by.CLASS_NAME, 'QualityControls__StyledButton-sc-1q6jsgy-3').click()
    print("hqelement worked")
except:
    print("hqelement didnt work")

sleep(5)
try:
    hdmarker = driver.find_element(by.XPATH, '//input[contains(@id, "0")]/parent::div[contains(@class, "inputBox__xWnjBeD9")]').click()
    print("marker worked")
except:
    print("marker didnt work")

sleep(15)
try:
    picture = driver.find_element(by.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "LiveViewGridSlot__IconButton-byp02h-4")]').click()
    sleep(5)
    print("picture worked")
except:
     print("picture didnt work")
sleep(5)
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def push_pictures():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('/root/token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('/root/token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                '/root/credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('/root/token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        upload_files_list = []
        for element in sorted(os.listdir("/root")):
            if element.__contains__("cam1"):
                upload_files_list.append(element)

        os.chdir("/root")
        for upload_file in sorted(upload_files_list):
            if upload_file.__contains__("DS_Store"):
                continue
            file_metadata = {'name': upload_file, 'parents': ['folderid']}
            media = MediaFileUpload(upload_file, mimetype='image/jpg')
            file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media).execute()
            print(F'File ID: {file.get("id")}')
            os.remove(upload_file)

    except HttpError as error:
        # Handle errors from drive API
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
        
push_pictures()

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

i have added all the sleeps in there, just to make sure the page had enough time to load, ill change those to await once I have figured out the problem.

When I run the code, the terminal output is without error and all of the prints are printing correctly, so the only problem is that it is not downloading even tho it is clicking on it.